# Getting "Received fatal alert: handshake_failure" in specific machine

Tags: java, ssl, proxy, ssl-certificate

I am running the same jar file in different machines. In one machine it is working fine, means while hitting different URL's able to get the proper response always.
But in another machine, at beginning all the URL's are working fine, after some period of time say 6 hours, it start throwing "handshake_failure" for few URL's (which are all working fine at beginning).

I understood that the "handshake_failure" may occurs due to SSL certificate issue or protocol issue (client and server has no common protocol)..

But here,

- Same URL is working during the start of application. So it wont be
  due to SSL certificate or protocol issue.
- Same URL is working during   the start of application, so it wont be
  due to the URL blocking from   the server , Like white-listing etc,,
- Also same jar file is used in both the machines , so it wont be due
  to code issue.
- Also application working fine once we start the application (restart
  the jar file).

Over all i suspect that there may be any chances of difference in any of configuration between the machines?

It would be great if any one can help me in this.

Exception:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure 
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:174) [na:1.6] 
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:136) [na:1.6] 
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:1720) [na:1.6] 
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:954) [na:1.6] 
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1138) [na:1.6] 
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:632) [na:1.6] 
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:59) [na:1.6] 
at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:65) [na:1.6.0_26] 
at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:123) [na:1.6.0_26] 
at org.owasp.webscarab.model.Request.writeDirect(Request.java:234) [webscarab-selfcontained-20070504-1631.jar:na] 
at org.owasp.webscarab.model.Request.writeDirect(Request.java:215) [webscarab-selfcontained-20070504-1631.jar:na] 
at org.owasp.webscarab.httpclient.URLFetcher.fetchResponse(URLFetcher.java:267) [siteprofiler.jar:na] 
at org.owasp.webscarab.plugin.proxy.ConnectionHandler.run(ConnectionHandler.java:346) [siteprofiler.jar:na] 
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [na:1.6.0_26]
```

Comment: have you imported required site certificate in the JRE/JDK you are using? Certificates should present inside jre/lib/cacert inorder to work with ssl based urls properly. http://www.grim.se/guide/jre-cert